# Why was my question on neologisms put on hold?

Tags: support, on-topic-off-topic, flagging

I asked one simple question ([Are there any general rules or guidelines for using newly coined word(s)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458328/are-there-any-general-rules-or-guidelines-for-using-newly-coined-words)) and it was put on hold. Nobody answered it and the moderator says that it will generate opinion. I doubt that. On the contrary, I have received 5 upvotes, so people are interested in it.

Comment: Your question is intersting, (that’s probably the reason for the upvotes)   but given the fact that there are no established rules about the usage of neologisms, any answer would necessarily be based  on the personal opinions of the posters.

Comment: @user070221  there is a comment by someone saying that there are some rules. My question can be wide, but surely it will not generate opinion. Does English language coin new words based on opinions?

Comment: there as to be some guidelines to use them

Comment: @user070221 I am not asking for strict rules, but general guidelines. I have update that part in my description.

Comment: @user070221 There are plenty of conventions, if not firm rules (pretty much like the rest of English usage). Style guides include guidelines for using slang, jargon and neologisms. New terms can be explicitly or implicitly defined when they are introduced. They might be prefixed with phrases like "so-called". They may be enclosed in "scare quotes" on first (or every) use. And so on and so on. This is not "opinion".

Comment: @JamesRandom that is what I am asking in that question, but someone put it on hold.

Comment: Actually, that question can serve as good general guide for using new words. Again, I am not asking for strict rules, just a general guideline.

Comment: @CarolineWo I know! I am really annoyed that it was put on hold. A massive abuse of power by one of the moderators.

Comment: @CarolineWo the person who put your question on hold is really a BIG SHOT: co developer of Perl language. I belong to Computer Science domain and I know that person. It is very hard that your question ever will get reopen again.  Good luck next time :)

Comment: @JamesRandom -  can you please cite reference for the suggested usages you are referring to. I’d like to know more about this “rules”.

Comment: @CarolineWo -  but are you looking for “rules” for coining new words or for using new words? In and case I really doubt there is any set rules on  those issue, but might be wrong.

Comment: @user070221 I am looking for how to use new words

Comment: @user070221 No, because the question was closed.

Comment: @JamesRandom - you can show your sources in an answer here, so users may vote to reopen the question on your evidence.

Comment: @user070221 The answer would (I hope) be criticised and possible removed for being off topic in the Meta forum. Also as, apparently, we are no longer allowed to provide answers based on style guides, you will have to google it yourself.

Comment: NOTE: Because the question has now been cross-posted to Writers, I have deleted it here. That is the usual procedure for cross-posts.

Comment: Your now-deleted original question is interesting—particularly when read in the context of the word you provide as an example (_cutease_). I feel sure that various style guides offer practical advice on when using such neologisms is suitable and when it is very likely to be unsuitable. In my view, the question is well worth researching and answering, and is on topic as a "writing-style" question—a category for which we have a tag. Note, however, that an active contingent of EL&U site participants will certainly oppose the question as inviting primarily opinion-based answers.

Comment: Related: [What is wrong with a discussion of opinion?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15318).

Comment: Voted to undelete -and- to reopen. It's interesting and intelligent answers can be given (non-opinionated ones, ones based on data).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could try asking the question at https://writing.stackexchange.com.

They may allow it to be discussed there.

I'm not sure as I haven't looked at that forum. (As a writer, perhaps I should!)

Comment: I am demotivated, but I will try. Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty off-topic for writers.SE. They would surely bounce it back to ELU given that it is more of a linguistic question. Since the OP is asking about English specifically, it is not really on-topic for linguistics.SE.